# Clojure. "lein test" executes file twice

Tags: clojure, tdd, clojurescript, leiningen

I'm trying to create my first tests on Clojure. I wrote [this file](https://github.com/aarkerio/ZentaurLMS/blob/e98542e877c8a7c30f008784e8ed5d40cf353bcb/test/clj/zentaur/models/tests_test.clj). When I run:

```
lein test
```

I got:

```
 ERROR in (update-question) (core.clj:32)
 Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
 expected: nil
   actual: 
              clojure.core/require        core.clj: 6007 (repeats 2 times)
            clojure.core/load-libs        core.clj: 5969
            clojure.core/load-libs        core.clj: 5985
            clojure.test/run-tests        test.clj:  768 (repeats 2 times)
                clojure.core/apply        core.clj:  667

  clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Parameter Mismatch: :id parameter data not found.
   java.lang.Exception: Exception in :get-one-question

FAIL in (create-answer) (tests_test.clj:63)
Create a new answer

expected: (not (nil? (:ordnen answer)))
 actual: (not (not true))

FAIL in (create-answer) (tests_test.clj:64)
  Create a new answer

expected: nil
  actual: "Some not so cool answer"

   diff: + "Some not so cool answer"
   2020-03-05 17:24:12,124 [main] INFO  zentaur.models.tests-test - >>> PA @first-user @first-user >>>>> {:email "grayson@me.com", :fname "Grayson", :lname "Barr", :active true, :id 72, :role_id 1, :uuid "efc8c516-04f1-4b22-a983-ed1e9c4f0da7"} 

 Ran 5 tests containing 7 assertions.
 **2 failures, 1 errors.**

Testing zentaur.models.tests-test
   2020-03-05 17:24:12,233 [main] INFO  zentaur.models.tests-test - >>> PARAM @first-question@first-question@first-question  >>>>> {:explanation "Explanation", :reviewed_fact false, :question "Some cool Question", :points 2, :hint "Some hint", :qtype 2, :updated_at #time/instant "2020-03-05T23:24:12Z", :reviewed_cr false, :active true, :id 71, :user_id 1, :origin 0, :fulfill nil, :created_at #time/instant "2020-03-05T23:24:12Z", :reviewed_lang false} 
  2020-03-05 17:24:12,849 [main] INFO  zentaur.models.tests-test - >>> PA @first-user @first-user >>>>> {:email "samantha@yahoo.com", :fname "Samantha", :lname "Good", :active true, :id 73, :role_id 1, :uuid "16d3eea4-3ed2-4636-a753-7fc0ec381e77"} 

Ran 5 tests containing 8 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

So, it looks like the test is executed twice but the first time with errors and the second correctly. I noticed the line:

```
            clojure.test/run-tests        test.clj:  768 (repeats 2 times)
```

but I don't why the file is called twice and why the first time some tests are "skipped". If I remove the line:

```
  (run-tests)
```

from the file, only the first (and wrong) time is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `(run-tests)` in the file.  The command `lein test`  will find all tests defined via `deftest` and run them for you.

Here is [a sample project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) you can clone and modify (try it w/o changes first to see an example of how it should look).

---

It is possible that your `mount` is doing something strange.  I personally don't like the "silent magic" that mount uses.  Also, I'm surprised it works for zentaur.config, zentaur.handler, and zentaur.db.core when they are not part of the `(:require ...)` expression.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan mentioned, (run-tests) is not necessary, that option usually is used in combination with "[with-test](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/with-test)".

As far as I could understand, before execute them, "lein test" gathers all the "deftest" in a vector that doesn't reflect the order in the file, so the last "deftest" are executed first. My solution was to nest the three "(testing " sections that I need to be executed sequentially in a "parent" *deftest*.